# O verbo "implicar", no sentido de requerer, é transitivo direto ou indireto?

Tags: verbos

As fontes que consultei dão como verbo transitivo direto quando o sentido é "requerer", "tornar indispensável", "trazer como consequência".  Por exemplo, "A criação artística implica muita dedicação".  O motivo da pergunta é que, no Brasil, sempre ouço "implicar" usado como verbo transitivo indireto. ("implica em muita dedicação", "aceitar esse compromisso implica em estar preparado para muitas despesas").  Falamos errado?

Comment: Leste [a definição de *implicar*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/implicar) no dicionário Priberam?

Comment: @tchrist  Sim, acabei de ler.  Nâo acrescenta nada ao que eu disse acima.

Comment: A resposta é basicamente *sim, falamos errado*.

Comment: Em Portugal ninguém diz coisas como "implica em muita dedicação." E como é que no Brasil, no estudo da lógica, se lê A => B? A implica B ou A implica em B? _Implica_ nestas frases significa basicamente _A trás como consequência B._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não estou a ver essa regência a ser usada em Portugal. Mesmo o Aulete digital [não lista](http://www.aulete.com.br/implicar) nenhum uso transitivo com em.

Procurando `"implica numa" site:pt` no Google temos 33 vezes menos resultados que com "implica uma", e a grande maioria tem complementos pelo meio ("implica, numa primeira fase"); há também algumas citações de pessoas brasileiras e outras construções distinguíveis ("os implicou numa" -- sentido 4 do Aulete).

Com `site:br`, o cenário é diferente com "implica uma" tendo apenas o dobro dos resultados.